# remove lines that math are duplicated based on a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with ~1,000,000 lines. That file has 400 fields but I am interested in the third file. An example how this file looks is this (in only outputting the first 8 fields and first 8 lines):

```
CHROM   POS     ID         REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO
chr1    693731  1:693731   A       G       .       PASS    AF=0.1294;MAF=0.1294;R2=0.5931;AC=29;AN=218        
chr1    715265  1:715265   C       T       .       PASS    AF=0.03657;MAF=0.03657;R2=0.35976;AC=6;AN=218        
chr1    715367  1:715367   A       G       .       PASS    AF=0.03785;MAF=0.03785;R2=0.38758;AC=7;AN=218        
chr1    717485  1:717485   C       A       .       PASS    AF=0.03738;MAF=0.03738;R2=0.3826;AC=7;AN=218        
chr1    720381  1:720381   G       T       .       PASS    AF=0.03843;MAF=0.03843;R2=0.38578;AC=8;AN=218        
chr1    721290  1:721290   G       C       .       PASS    AF=0.03823;MAF=0.03823;R2=0.38292;AC=8;AN=218        
chr1    723891  rs2977670  G       C       .       PASS    AF=0.9529;MAF=0.0471;R2=0.34792;AC=209;AN=218
chr1    726794  1:726794   C       G       .       PASS    AF=0.03769;MAF=0.03769;R2=0.40295;AC=8;AN=218
```

I have some lines that has duplicated the `ID` field, I can pull this entries out using

```
 cat myfile | cut -f3 | awk '{a[$0]++; if(a[$0]==2) print; if (a[$0]>=2) print}'
```

Example output of above command:

```
1:186936590
1:186936590
10:54530788
10:54530788
14:50274280
14:50274280
17:51326717
17:51326717
```

What I want is to remove one of the duplicated entries but keeping the other one. The field `ID` is the only that is duplicated, the rest of the line is different so I think I can't use `awk '!a[$0]++'`

Any suggestions?

Comment: The output is not corresponding to the given input? Can you update the set properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following `awk` command to do this, we check the hashed value count per `$3` value to be less than 2

```
awk 'NR==1 || unique[$3]++ < 2' file
```

The condition `unique[$3]++ < 2` specifically means that print the line until it sees the value in `$3` for the 2nd time. For subsequent iterations the value will be greater than 2 on which the line won't be printed.

```
$ printf 'id\n1\n2\n1\n2\n1\n2\n' | awk 'NR==1 || unique[$0]++ < 2'
id 
1
2
1
2
```

The condition `NR==1` asserts true only for the first line containing the header information which is printed.

Comment: Thanks @Inian, but I wanted to keep only one line of the duplicates so I will do `awk 'NR==1 || unique[$0]++ < 1'`